# Memcache not working at prestashop

Tags: prestashop

I'm trying to understand why memcache won't work at prestashop, it makes the page load 10 times slower in the product page.

I've tested APC cache in production and takes the server load to above 4.

Server & versions :

- nginx/1.1.19
- PHP 5.3.10-1ubuntu3.6 (fpm-fcgi)
- memcached 1.4.13
- PrestaShop 1.5.3.1
- installed at server: pecl, pear, php-dev, libpcre3-dev, pcre-devel, libmemcached-dev and all required stuff
- memcache process : `26507 ?        Sl     0:05 /usr/bin/memcached -m 64 -p 11211 -u memcache -l 127.0.0.1`
- memcache configured to `127.0.0.1 / 11211 / Weight=1`
- no error logs

memcache on (`3 seconds`) :
[image: memcache]

no cache (`300ms`):
[image: no cache]

APC (`100ms`):
[image: APC]

Comment: Try ServerFault for more help: http://serverfault.com/search?q=slow+memcached